# What does the IntelliSense error "public data members are not allowed in non-value types" mean?

Tags: c++-cli, intellisense, c++-cx

I'm taking over a C++ CLI project and one of the files, `StartScreen.xaml.h`, is throwing an IntelliSense error in Visual Studio 2013. Here's a fragment of the code:

```
public ref class StartScreen sealed
{
public:
    StartScreen();

    void SetApp(App^ app);

    void ShowProgressRing();
    void HideProgressRing();

internal:
    static float imagePercentage;
    ....
```

It's that last line that's causing the problem. `imagePercentage` throws the error

```
108 IntelliSense: public data members are not allowed in non-value types
```

What does this mean and how (if at all - it compiles without compiler errors) should I fix it?

Comment: Make this member private and add internal Get/Set properties.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I changed it to private. It was only used in the related cpp file so I didn't bother with the internal accessor and setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it is just a bug in IntelliSense.  C++/CLI and C++/CX share a syntax, but it seems that there are some rules that are different.  In this case, C++/CX doesn't allow public/internal fields:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/20db7069-3e49-4772-8b9a-0c80490e0dea/error-c3984-a-nonvalue-type-cannot-have-any-public-data-members?forum=winappswithnativecode
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699870

C++/CLI has no such restriction (that's why it compiles for you).  The Intellisense is probably just (incorrectly) sharing this rule between both C++/CLI and C++/CX.

If you really do want an internally visible field, I would just ignore the Intellisense.  If it bothers you, and you can change it to a property, then that's your workaround.